# Querying Mongoose in Body of POST Request

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, mongoose

I have been passing into the body of a POST request in my Angular app, a query which is handled by Mongoose in order to return a subset of data. So, for instance, I've been able to pass this into the body of the request:

```
{ "snapshot.a": "consulting" }
```

And this is for a property on the root of the document that looks like this:

```
{
    snapshot: 
          { 
           a: value 
          }
}
```

All the above worked as expected.

However, now I have a situation where the data now looks like this:

```
{
    snapshot: 
          { 
           a: value,
           b: value,
           c: value
          }
}
```

I'm stumped as to what I can pass in the body of my POST request to handle returning data when the queried value (for instance, a value like "consulting") matches for ANY of "a", "b", or "c". I've tried putting a, b, and c in an array, but that gets me zero results. And if I wrap the entire thing in an array, it returns the entire data set -- i.e. no filtering is happening. How would I handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: Something like `db.collection_name.find( { $or: [ { "snapshot.a": "consulting" }, { "snapshot.b": "consulting" } ...] } )`

Comment: Thanks, @Veeram, I will take a look at something like this.